# printbibliography outside of \include{Chapters/Chaptername}

Tags: bibliographies, chapters

I am using the scrbook class and compiling through PDFLaTeX.  I have my document setup such that I include the different chapters that each have their own \cite, but would like to print one bibliography only at the end of the whole \mainmatter, not after each chapter.  When I try that, no bibliography prints.  Here are some of the document lines:

```
 \documentclass[%
   ,paper=a4    
   ,pagesize=auto
   ,BCOR=0.75cm 
%   ,oneside     
   ,DIV=10       
%   ,DIV=calc    
   ,numbers=noenddot 
   ,captions=heading 
   ,captions=nooneline 
   ,listof=totoc 
   ,bibliography=totoc 
   ,index=totoc  
   ,headings=normal 
%   ,headings=small  
   ,USenglish,   
]{scrbook}
%

\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}   \addbibresource{C:/Users/bossman/Desktop/FAU/ModernControl/References/chap1.bib}



\addbibresource{C:/Users/bossman/Desktop/FAU/ModernControl/References/chap1.bib}% BibTeX
 \defbibheading{bibempty}{}
 \newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
%\listoftables

\include{Chapters/Intro}

\mainmatter

\include{Chapters/Solution1}
\include{Chapters/Solution2}

\backmatter
% no thumb index
\lohead[]{}

\printbibliography
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title=\bibname]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=book, title={Books}]
\printbibliography[type=online, heading=subbibintoc, title={Online}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,title={Articles}]

\end{document}
```

How can I go about printing the bibliography only at the end of the document?

Comment: Your document does not work and it's quite tedious to make it work. After all, I got multiple bibliographies, just because you've specified four `\printbibliography` terms. But there are no`per-chapter` bibliographies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it appears, as to why the bibliography did not appear in my output document was due to the fact that my Chapter 2 was empty.  If I just commented out

```
\include{Chapters/Solution2}
```

the bibliography showed up as it was only in Chapter 1 that I had text and also the \cite.